# Embedding a predefined SQLITE doc in Core Data Application

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Thanks for the help. I have a woking Core Data doc based app. that solely supports SQLITE docs. I would like to distribute the application with a previously created database document with predefined data embedded in the application bundle.

How do I instruct the application to run the embedded file at runtime?

thanks.

-paul.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What do you mean by "running" a "document"?  It's a database, right?  Do you want to run SELECT queries on it?  Doesn't the application code do that?

Comment: I want the application to display the saved database that is embedded in the project bundle when the user launches the app.

-paul.

Comment: For example lets assume the app stores employee contact info. I want to distribute the app to the staff with predefined data. I would populate the app with the necessary data and save the SQLITE doc as normal.

I want to embed that previously saved SQLITE document into the application bundle so that when the staff installs and runs the app, all of my inserted and saved data will be available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you'd do is store a copy of the file in the `Resources` directory of your application bundle. From there, it depends on what kind of application you have. If it's a single document application (like iPhoto, for example), You could copy the file to the `~/Application Support/Your Application` directory so that your app will open it by default.

Take a look inside the application delegate class (I'm assuming you're using the template provided with Xcode?) to see how it generates the path to the application file. You basically just have to make sure that the file exists at that path when the application starts up.

In this case, `NSFileManager` and the `pathForResource:ofType:` method of `NSBundle` are your friends.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I will look into this.

-paul.